# Unable to compile code on LaTeX

Tags: equations

```
\begin{align}

    y_{t} = {\alpha + \beta_ {1}x_{1t} + \sum_{j=1}^3 (\delta_{j}Q_{jt}+ \varepsilon_{t})}
    \text{where Q_{jt} = 1} \hspace{5}\text{if in quarter} \hspace{5} j, 0 \hspace{5} \text{otherwise}
\end{align}
```

[image: I am trying to get to this result]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. But you haven't actually asked a question. Instead of posting a fragment of code as you have, please put the fragment into a complete compilable document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Do you get an error? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: as well as a test file it helps if you show the error that you get. But here I guess your error is `\hspace{5}`  the argument needs to be a length. eg `\hspace{5pt}`

Comment: It seems that problem is empty line after `begin{align`. Removing it will solve your main problem.

Answer (score 5):

The following code does what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath} %maths

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    y_{t} = \alpha + \beta_{1} x_{1t} + \sum_{j=1}^3 \delta_{j}Q_{jt} + \varepsilon_{t}, \; \text{where $Q_{jt} = 1$ if in quarter $j$, $0$ otherwise} 
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend your code fragment to an MWE (Minimal WOrking Example), which OP (and we, others) can test and which will solve OP main problem (see my comment below question).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just edited my answer.

Comment: +1 now! Happy TeXing!

Comment: +1 but allow me a small comment: when an obviously unexperienced user asks for help, besides giving correct code as answer try to explain what s/he did wrong. In this way the OP will learn what was wrong with the code and will (hopefully) avoid analogous errors in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Some suggestions:

- Don't use an `align` environment for a single-line equation; instead, use an `equation` environment.
- Don't allow all-blank lines in display-math environments.
- Streamline your code by replacing

  ```
  \text{where Q_{jt} = 1} \hspace{5}\text{if in quarter} \hspace{5} j, 0 \hspace{5} \text{otherwise}
  ```

  with

  ```
  \text{where $Q_{jt} = 1$ if in quarter $j$, $0$ otherwise}
  ```
- Further streamline your code by omitting the redundant outer pair of curly braces in

  ```
  {\alpha + \beta_ {1}x_{1t} + \sum_{j=1}^3 (\delta_{j}Q_{jt}+ \varepsilon_{t})}
  ```

  and absolutely get rid of the round parentheses in `(\delta_{j}Q_{jt}+ \varepsilon_{t})`. For sure, the `\varepsilon_t` term does not belong in the parenthetic expression.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\text" macro

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  y_{t} = \alpha + \beta_{1}x_{1t} + \sum_{j=1}^3 \delta_{j}Q_{jt}+ \varepsilon_{t}
  \quad\text{where $Q_{jt} = 1$ if in quarter $j$, $0$ otherwise}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```